# Java Create Test JMS message for unit test, IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms

```
public interface MessageWrapper {
    public void setMessage(Message message);
}
```

I  want to create test Message(JMS) for unit test, without creating session and don't connect at all.
How can I  create test JMS message and write content in it. I use Tomcat + (for JMS) IBM JMS implementations.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory) may help you
It offers many feature to deal with Q provider and a REST interface to put and get messages, manage templates, generates messages with variables etc